# aws ssm get-parameter rsa key output to file

Tags: amazon-web-services, sed

I have stored my private key file in AWS SSM Parameter store. I want to retrieve just the private key value from the parameter store and save it as an id_rsa file locally using aws cli.

This article: https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/2742 shows me exactly how i can do that using `sed`. however I still get a character returned after `"-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"` which i want to remove using `sed`.

This is my command i run on command line:

```
aws --region=us-east-1 ssm get-parameters --names "mykey" --with-decryption --output text 2>&1 | sed 's/.*----BEGIN/----BEGIN/'
```

And the output is:

```
----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
some text here
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----   2
```

Notice the `2` in the end of the last line. I want to get rid of anything after `-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` as well.

What do i need to add to my `sed` command to achieve that?

Comment: Why do you need `2>&1` ? Are you redirecting stderr to stdout? Why? Remove `2>&1` and it should fix your problem.

Comment: I did remove `2>&1` as you are right, it is not needed. However that still does not remove the trailing `2` in the end of the last line. So by adding the following did give me the desired output: `sed 's/KEY-----.*/KEY-----/'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line fixed my problem:

```
aws --region=us-east-1 ssm get-parameters --names "mykey" --with-decryption --output text 2>&1 | sed 's/.*----BEGIN/----BEGIN/' | sed 's/KEY-----.*/KEY-----/' > id_rsa
```

Answer (score 76):

You can obtain the value alone using the following command:

```
aws --region=us-east-1 ssm get-parameter --name "mykey" --with-decryption --output text --query Parameter.Value
```

i.e. by selecting the value using `--query Parameter.Value`

You can then pipe it directly to the file without using sed.

Comment: This seems to have been updated to `--query "Parameters[*].Value"` per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ssm/get-parameters.html

Answer (score 3):

Additional option:

```
aws --region=us-east-1 ssm get-parameters --names "mykey" --with-decryption | jq -r '.Parameter.Value'
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

For me the most usefull way to get parameters from AWS SSM is this one:

```
aws ssm get-parameter --name mykey --with-decryption --region us-east-1 | jq -r '.Parameter.Value'
```

After that you can check the output and "play" with **sed** command.

Answer (score 0):

`aws ssm get-parameter --name "YOURNAME-secret1" --with-decryption | jq -r ".Parameter.Value"` works for me and i got it from https://mng.workshop.aws/ssm/capability_hands-on_labs/parameterstore.html scroll all the way to the bottom of the page